# Accept only 12 comma seperated values for input type text html5

Tags: javascript, php, regex, html

I want my input tag to accept only maximum 12 comma separated values.it should not accept values like  `1,` mean after comma their is nothing 
this is the regex i have made.i think regex syantax in php and JavaScript 
is same

```
 [0-9a-zA-z]+(,[0-9a-zA-z]+){12}$
```

but it is not working
Here is my whole code

```
<form action="demo_form.php">
  <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[0-9a-zA-z]+(,[0-9a-zA-z]+){12}$" title="only 12 comma separated vaue">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Kindly help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps, you need [`^[^,]*(,[^,]*){11}$`](https://regex101.com/r/mK3kN0/1)

Comment: @stribizhev it is not accepting values less than 12 also it is accepting as, space text after comma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this regex will work out for you.

```
^[0-9a-zA-z]+(,[0-9a-zA-z]+){0,11}$
```

You can test your regular expressions in this [site](http://regexpal.com/). Its, awesome.

Comment: First, you were not adding ^ at the start of the regex, and second, u were using {12} which strictly takes 12 repetitions, but we need {1, 11} which takes 1 to 11 repetitions, 11 since u need 12 and we already have one at the beginning.

Comment: can you also help me understanding this (,[0-9a-zA-z]+) i am having confusion in this also Thanks

Comment: I suggest you go through [RegexOne](http://regexone.com). The lessons there cleared all my doubts regarding regular expressions.

Comment: okay i will but if you have time then kindly share your knowledge with me thanks again

Comment: It's quite simple, the regex will accept any character that starts with a Comma(,) and has atleast one Number(0-9) or lowercase alphabet(a-z) or Uppercase alphabet(A-Z). The expression + means, that at least one.

Comment: ^[0-9a-zA-z]+(,[0-9a-zA-z]+){1,11}$ is not working for 1 value like hello checked this on http://www.phpliveregex.com/ kinldly help me

Comment: Thanks  Parthapratim Neog i will check it